# Does IntelliJ have an internal web server to serve static content of a web application?

Tags: intellij-idea, web-applications, built-in-web-server

Right now, the directory of my module is defined as an IIS virtual directory and IIS serves the files.

I was wondering whether IntelliJ has an internal web server, which can serve the files, without the need for any third party. Eclipse [does](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Fthttppreview.html).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**UPDATE:** built-in web server is available in the recent IntelliJ IDEA versions (starting from 13). You can find [more details in the blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/03/built-in-server-in-webstorm-6/) (yes, this feature first appeared in WebStorm).

<s>IntelliJ IDEA has no this feature, you need to install and use any third-party web server that can serve the content from the project folders.</s>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For future visitors: just watch this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/EKiP9b8ikTY). You need to add new 'JavaScript Debug' configuration.

Comment: @naXastandswithUkraine, the youtube video link is no more valid

Comment: @rinilnath new video: https://youtu.be/YNNDMpoGV0w (Debugging JS in WebStorm and Chrome)

Answer (score 8):

A built-in HTTP preview server will be part of Intellij IDEA 13 and is already available in the EAP: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7148

> "All existing actions — preview in browser (pop-up over html file or menu action or 
>   shortcut), open in browser and create/debug html file action now open file on built-in web 
>   server 
>   `http://localhost:63342/<project name>/<file path relative to source or content root>`"

In other words, right-click on an HTML page and select "Debug" or "Open in browser", and IDEA 13+ will serve up that page via port 63342.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another super simple option, install Python: http://www.python.org/getit/

Then open a shell prompt, navigate to your root web folder (e.g. public) and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` - This starts an HTTP Service on port 8000.

Further reading should you need it: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python

I've got mine running on Windows 7 but the above article still applies.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is is create a PHP project that, starting with v 5.4.0 of PHP includes a built in web server.  This page explains it all ...

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/php-built-in-web-server.html

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA has a [built-in web server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/php-built-in-web-server.html) that can be used to preview and debug your application. Just watch this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/EKiP9b8ikTY) or follow the steps below.

#### Option 1

You need to add new 'JavaScript Debug' configuration:

- Click Add Configuration... or Edit Configurations... in the [Navigation bar](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigation-bar.html)

  [image: Run | Edit Configurations]
- Click [image: +] button in the toolbar or press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to create a new configuration
- Select [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) under the Templates node in the tree view of run configurations
- Fill in Name, URL, Browser and click [OK] to save the configuration
  Use `http://localhost:63342/YOUR-PROJECT-NAME/index.html` for URL

  [image: Run/Debug Configurations Dialog]

Now you can run the configuration:

- Click run [image: run icon] or debug [image: debug icon] button in the Navigation bar (or use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> hotkeys).

#### Option 2

Running web page in browser without creating a configuration. Refer to the related IntelliJ IDEA [Help article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javascript-specific-guidelines.html#open_html).

> 1. In the editor, open the HTML file. This HTML file does not necessarily have to be the one that implements the starting page of the application.
> 2. Do one of the following:
>
>    - Choose **View | Open in Browser** on the main menu or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Then select the desired browser from the pop-up menu.
>    - Hover your mouse pointer over the code to show the browser icons bar:  [image: browser icons]. Click the icon that indicates the desired browser.

#### Result

Google Chrome browser with a demo web page served by the Intelij IDEA's built-in webserver:

[image: demo web page]

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to create a NodeJS / Express project in IntelliJ that ***is*** your web server.  You can then use it to serve your static web pages and any other web content. The NodeJS web server is very small and runs fast - noticeably faster than IIS and Apache. Best of all you can just hit the Run button in IntelliJ or WebStorm to start it up.

By default, a NodeJS / Express project includes a `public/` directory that you can use to contain your static pages that you can then view from `http://localhost:3000/`

This explains the steps required to enable NodeJS in IntelliJ and includes links to other Node resources:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/node-js.html

If you feel the need, you can reconfigure your NodeJS server using server side Javscript code. You can add SSL support or almost any other server side features you care to dream up. Just add NodeJS modules using the npm (Node Package Manager) command line tool included with the install. NPM Registry https://npmjs.org/ indexes all the available modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure IntelliJ to use a lot of different application containers, but each of them must be downloaded and installed separately. I currently have mine configured to serve via jetty, like eclipse, and also tomcat, tc-server, jboss, and node.js. It's pretty easy to set up.