# "Publish" the IntelliJ static web server

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998481/does-intellij-have-an-internal-web-server-to-serve-static-content-of-a-web-appli), I have a new one.

Is there any way to remotely access the IntelliJ static web server?

I need to access from a cellphone, but I can only access to the server if I use `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`. Doesn't work if I try to access by my local IP ("192.168.0.10").

I googled it and I can't found where I can configure the static server.

Comment: You've tried accessing it using the server's IP instead of just 127.0.0.1 or localhost right?

Comment: Yup. Thats the problem :).

Comment: @powerMock - I reverted [the revision you made](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26536813/2) to this question that removed OP's comment about googling this; that indicates *some* level of research, which is precisely what *should* be kept in the question.

Comment: @admdrew
It was your choice. I suppose that every person should search for a solution ( at least 5 minutes ) before posting a question on SO. This is why I considered that row to be redundant and I tried to simplify the post.

Comment: @powerMock I TOTALLY agree (and the upvote/downvote mouseovers even allude to needing research), it's just that many users don't actually do that research, so it's nice to see someone did (especially for new/low rep users).